# Is it possible to bring back Aero preview on alt+tab in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, aero

Back in Windows 7, when one presses alt+tab the "Windows Flip" menu appears and if (s)he holds alt but stops pressing tab, a preview of the app appears. In Windows 10, the behaviour is different: the menu looks different (not sure if it can be still refered as "Windows Flip") and holding alt without pressing tab doesn't bring the preview. While I'm ok with the menu itself, I wonder if there's a way to bring the preivew back.

The problem is also described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4ceea0a-5bf6-410e-9fc5-642c15ec5cff/alt-tab-aero-peek-not-working-the-same-as-before?forum=win10itprogeneral); let me bring the screenshot from there to illustrate what preview I'm talking about:

[image: Windows 7 showing alt-tab peek][image: Windows 10 not showing alt-tab peek]

(I add the windows-7 tag so that gentlemen familiar with its internals may help too)

**PS** As mentioned in comments, Aero Peek works for me for previewing desktop (when cursor hovers over bottom right corner thing on TaskBar); and also works with elements on TaskBar (hover mouse over an element → get a smaller preview; hover mouse over that preview → get full window preview which is what I miss when using alt+tab).

Comment: @Ramhound probably yes (although I'm not sure), but different elements of Windows 7 can be brought by third-party software, may be there's such a solution? I'm already using ClassicShell to get back Start Menu like in Windows 7..

Comment: My aplogizes. Just Right click on the taskbar and go to Properties and hit the checkbox next to Use Aero Peek to preview the desktop

Comment: @Ramhound this checkbox is already checked on my PC.. Yes, Aero Peek works for desktop; but it doesn't work with the alt+tab interface.

Comment: I don't understand.  Showing a screenshot from Windows 7 does not really clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Not sure what to clarify.. Here are the steps to reproduce the behaviour in Windows 7: open a couple of windows one hovering above another; hold alt, press tab; release tab, hold alt for ~1 sec. The open window becomes transparent and the second one is now visible ("preview".. or may be it's not a proper term?). On the screenshot, you can see at least 2 transparent windows (more to the left) and the one which I call a preview (chosen in Window Flip). In Windows 10 doing same thing doesn't make other windows transparent, so one doesn't see the currently chosen window.

Comment: I think it's possible with third party. However, your desired 'preview' is accessible from the Taskbar when you hover the cursor on the icon of one programme and hover again on the pop-up window's thumbnail. Perhaps you should mention this on your question so people know what are you describing.

Comment: I see what you're trying to achieve (and I think the Windows 7 screenshot is perfectly relevant). It seems as though this is yet another missing feature in Windows 10. Much like the "feature" of the Details pane being stuck on the right of the screen instead of down the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not appear to be in Windows 10. Maybe you should submit feedback through the Windows 10 Feedback Hub.

Comment: @YakovL Does the Windows Key+Tab work for what you want?

Comment: @MrStatic why, not at all. I'm talking about aero previews (full size ones) and win+tab only shows what alt+tab does without necessity to hold alt

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no.

This is because only a few Aero effects actually continued on from Vista and 7

Those effects are Aero desktop peek, and Aero task-bar peek (names I just gave them to allow for most people to understand)

there might be some programs that return something similar, but they can't use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> as it is now a protected system shortcut

I will request that feature in the Windows Feedback Hub for you, and I hoe the return the functionality, as it was very nice

Comment: I had seen another request and I also upvoted it in the Windows Feedback  Hub

Comment: Could you please add the exact names of your suggestion and of another that you've found, I'll go upvote them :)

Comment: @YakovL just search for it